# Not playing youtube videos swift 5

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, swift5, youtubeplayer

Embedding the YouTubePlayerView to play youtube videos but not working as nothing happens. Below is the code i am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var youtubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView!

@IBAction func playYoutube(_ sender: Any) {

    btnYoutube.isHidden = true


    // Load video from YouTube ID
   // videoPlayer.loadVideoID("lRW6CYfhei0") //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRW6CYfhei0


    // Load video from YouTube URL
    let myVideoURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRW6CYfhei0")
    videoPlayer.loadVideoURL(myVideoURL! as URL)

}
```

Please guide what is missing.

Comment: why are you not loading video with video ID,
**playerView.loadWithVideoId("lRW6CYfhei0")**

Comment: @ShubhDev it isn't working as well

Comment: Below code working in my project


`@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnClick.isHidden = true
        let playerVars: [String: Any] = [
            "controls": 0,
            "modestbranding": 1,
            "playsinline": 0,
            "autoplay": 1,
            "origin": "https://youtube.com"
        ]
        playerView.delegate = self
        //playerView.loadWithVideoId("lRW6CYfhei0")
        playerView.loadWithVideoId("lRW6CYfhei0", with: playerVars)
    }`

Comment: It isn't   videoPlayer.playerVars = [ "controls": 0,
        "modestbranding": 1,
        "playsinline": 0,
        "autoplay": 1,
        "origin": "https://youtube.com" ]
        videoPlayer.delegate = self as? YouTubePlayerDelegate
        videoPlayer.loadVideoID("lRW6CYfhei0")

Comment: did you use two-player youtubePlayerView & videoPlayer?
may be written by mistake?

Comment: you have to load youtube video in youtubePlayerView.

Comment: let videoPlayer = YouTubePlayerView(frame: youtubePlayerView.frame)

Answer (score 0):

Video url is wrong. It is a url for watching on the browser.

Video url for the function "loadVideoByUrl" has a different format.
You can check here.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

And here is an alternative solution for you.

```
playerview.delegate = self
playerView.loadWithVideoId("lRW6CYfhei0")
```

It should work.